# Stern-Gerlach Experiment vertical atom distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, electrons, quantum-spin

From some of the videos covering the Stern-Gerlach experiment I noticed that electrons / silver atoms that are shot through the magnet are visualized to spread not only into two distinct horizontal sections, but also verically. Is there a specific reason for it?

[image]

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FC_A4XUlZyg&t=167s

Comment: Have you estimated diffraction effects, and emittance  of the source beam?

Comment: No, sorry I am very new to physics XD. And also I have seen such behavior in many videos - that's the reason why I raised the question. To figure out whether it's just a source beam inaccuracy stuff or something related to electron spin properties.

Comment: It's definitely NOT related to spin. It's just a wave going through an aperture, probably. But I don't enough about the apparatus to post an answer.